# Connect to mongodb via ssh tunnel failing

Tags: mongodb, ssh, mongodb-atlas, ssh-tunnel, mongo-connector

I have tried to connect to my mongodb on a server i own via an ssh tunnel via the following apps but nothing will connect:

- compass
- robomongo
- nosqlbooster4mongo
- phpstorm inbuilt mongodb java connector

Server and mongo:

- Server: ubuntu 18lts
- Mongo: latest community version

The Connection URL in all instances is the same (also tried removing the query params) and this url works on the node app:

> mongodb://localhost:27017/data-aggregator?retryWrites=true&w=majority

nosqlbooster4mongo's error message is:
[image]
But the connection url is 27017 and gets changed to 37903 for some reason
[image]

PHPStorm's error message is:

> DBMS: Mongo DB Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=mixed Driver:
> MongoDB JDBC Driver (ver. 1.13, JDBC4.2) Effective version: UNKNOWN
> (ver. 0.0) Ping: 10 sec, 289 ms (keep-alive query results in error)
>
> Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of
> cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:42865,
> type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
> exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving
> message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}].

Nothing works but i cannot understand why.

The SSH connection is working as confirmed by nosqlbooster4mongo and phpstorm

But as soon as it then tries to connect to the local mongodb instance it fails. I don't know if this is an issue with the SSH tunnel or the mongo setup. Via a terminal i can connect to mongo no issue, also the node app there can too.

The tunnels are using the same key as i use to connect to the server via terminal without issue which leads me to believe it is mongo but i don't know where to look :/

As the tunnel is established, then this says the server firewalls are not an issue.

I don't know what it is, is there an additional query param for ssh tunnel access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @Jack_Woehr on:  https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-5-community-edition-cannot-connect-via-tunnel/151526

The trick was to not use the ssh tunnel from any of the tools listed and just create a the tunnel on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of ssh servers on debian based (ubuntu, popos...) don't allow every type of ssh key authentication.

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the line:

```bash
# Allow all types of secure keys
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512
```

Restart running: `sudo systemctl restart sshd`